# Rails 3 Devise Customize Redirection for Registrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise 1.5.3.

I inherited **`Devise::RegistrationsController`** for customizing my own path for after_update:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
   protected
   def after_update_path_for(resource)
     some_path
   end 
end
```

After that Rails tries to find views for registration actions (new, create, etc) in **`views/registrations/`** but no in **`/views/devise/registrations`**

Sure, I can copy all from **`/views/devise/registrations`** to **`views/registrations/`**. But it's not suitable for me, because rest of my view (for not customized controllers) still are in **`/views/devise/registrations`**.

How Can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should work if you scope your RegistrationsController into Devise's scope:

```
class Devise::MyRegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  # ...
end
```

Of course you can't use the same name for the RegistrationsController and you have rename the `views/devise/registrations` folder to `views/devise/my_registrations` and you have to update your routes.rb file as well... but with this setup it should work...

Another option, I think, would be to overwrite/inject the method in an initializer:

```
class Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected
  def after_update_path_for(resource)
    some_path
  end 
end
```

which may be simpler...

Answer (score 1):

Building on Vapire's answer. I think the inject option is simplest/best.

Because I want to include a permanent 'Edit my Registration' in the navbar, so that it can be called from any page,I also want to send the user back to the page they clicked from.

I found a simple way to do this was to override some of the controller behaviour and use a session variable to capture the referring path. Using a session variable keeps the referrer path intact if the form has to be reloaded to correct errors.

routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations=>'users/registrations'}
```

controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def edit
    session[:called_from]=request.referer 
    super #revert to standard behaviour
  end

  def after_update_path_for(resource)
    session[:called_from] #returns to the page called from
  end

 end
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer by @Vapire does not work for me for Rails 4. I had to override the Devise Passwords controller like this:

```
# users/passwords_controller.rb
class Users::PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
 protected
 def after_resetting_password_path_for(resource)
  signed_in_root_path(resource)
 end
end
```

There is documentation on this method here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in